# $and in reactive mongo with play framework 2.6

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I' am using play framework v2.6 with scala, I'am using reactivemongo as driver for mongodb, my problem is I do not know how to retrieve objects having  values that are between  two values.In my example  i have this case class :

```
case class Card (id : String, creationDate: Date)
```

I want to retrieve cards that have a creation date between two dates so i used this query:

```
val query = BSONDocument(
         "$and" -> BSONDocument(
         "creationDate" -> Json.obj("$gte" ->startDate),
         "creationDate" -> Json.obj("$lte" ->endDate))
         )
```

but this outputs the following error:

```
A server error occurred DatabaseException['Can't canonicalize query:       
BadValue and needs an array' (code = 17287)]
```

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory (and not specific to ReactiveMongo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) the `$and` operator needs an array:

```
val query = BSONDocument(
  "$and" -> BSONArray(List(
    BSONDocument("creationDate" -> Json.obj("$gte" ->startDate)),
    BSONDocument("creationDate" -> Json.obj("$lte" ->endDate))
  ))
)
```